# Making an object with comma separated values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to create an object that hold values like below:

```
var object = [{A: 1,2,3,3,2,5,6}]
              {B: 2,4,5,6,1,7,2}]
```

and so on. Is this possible? I have tried it the way I have shown above and I get a syntax error. I want to keep them as INTs not as a string.

Comment: Why would this get down voted it is a legitimate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var object = [
               {A: [1,2,3,3,2,5,6]},
               {B: [2,4,5,6,1,7,2]}
             ];
```